# Breaking at a member function in the Python debugger

Tags: python, debugging

This should be a trivial question, but my search so far has been fruitless:

I'm using the Python debugger (pdb) for the first time, and was quite pleased to find most of the commands familiar from using gdb.

However, when I went to set a breakpoint in the *parse*() member of class *JamParser* with the statement:

```
(Pdb) b JamParser.parse
*** The specified object 'JamParser.parse' is not a function
or was not found along sys.path.
```

I tried several several variants, including:

```
(Pdb) b jam2dot.py:JamParser.parse
```

I assume that since I invoked the debugger from the command line that it knows the entities in the file.  Is that a false assumption?

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html) says that break can take a function as an argument, but doesn't offer any syntax help.  So how do I set a breakpoint for a member function by name?

Comment: IF you have access to the source, I usually drop a `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` where I want rather than step through with the debugger.

Comment: @Noufal: Now that I'm a bit more experienced, I've realized the value of your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. I learned this trick from a bunch of Python pros at PyCon two years ago. :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to import names before you can refer to them in the debugger.

```
(Pdb) from jam2dot import JamParser
(Pdb) b JamParser.parse
```

Comment: Wow. What an awful, misleading error message. If a program *can't find* something, it should say so, rather than implying that it found it but it wasn't the right sort of thing.

Comment: Yes, it's rather poor, isn't it? The trouble is that the `b` command takes *either* a filename, *or* a function, so the error message has to respect this ambiguity (after all, maybe you wanted a breakpoint in the file named `JamParser.py` and mis-typed the extension). But I agree that it could do a lot better than this. I suggest you submit a bug report!

Comment: this may be a quite old post, but why the pdb module does not automatically import members of a file that is actually being debugged?

Comment: This should be included as an example in the [pdb documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html).

Comment: @IainSamuelMcLeanElder Ten years later, my advice is the same: submit a bug report and a patch!